# Check for Partial Match in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JavaScript array that contains some words that cannot be used when requesting user accounts to be created.

I am trying to loop over the accounts requested and check them against a word filter. If they contain any of the words, the value is moved to an array of "Invalid Accounts".

```
// Create our arrays
var blacklist = ["admin", "webform", "spoof"];
var newAccounts = ["admin1@google.com", "interweb@google.com", "puppy@google.com"];
var invalidAccounts = [];

// I need to check if any of the new accounts have matches to those in the blacklist. 
// admin1@google.com would need to be pushed into the invalidAccounts array because it 
// contains the word admin. Although interweb contains the word web, it does not contain 
// the full word, webform, so should be ignored.

// Loop over the blacklist array
for(var x = 0; x < blacklist.length; x++){
  if(blacklist[x].indexOf(newAccounts) > -1){
    alert(blacklist[x] + " is in the blacklist array");
    // Push the newAccounts value into the invalidAccounts array since it contains
    // a blacklist word.
  } else {
    alert('no matches');
  }
}
```

What do I need to change in the above code to have it match the partial strings such as mentioned?

Fiddle of above code: https://jsfiddle.net/1qwze81o/

Comment: You need to loop twice (as things are set up now). Personally, I'd loop over `newAccounts` first, and check each of those against each of the `blacklist` contents. Seems pretty straight-forward.

Comment: You could test the blacklist entry against the email, not the other way. Moreover, you have webform in your blacklist, not web. So if you filter emails containing web, you have to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't need to use all of this but it should be helpful none the less:

```
var blacklist = ["admin", "webform", "spoof"];
var newAccounts = ["admin1@google.com", "interweb@google.com", "puppy@google.com"];
var invalidAccounts = [];

// transform each email address to an object of the form:
// { email: string, valid: boolean }
var accountObjects = newAccounts.map(function (a) {
    return { email: a, valid: true };
});

// loop over each account
accountObjects.forEach(function (account) {
    // loop over the blacklisted terms
    blacklist.forEach(function (blacklisted) {
        // check to see if your account email address contains a black listed term
        // and set the valid property accordingly
        account.valid = account.email.search(blacklisted) === -1;
    });
});

// filter accountObjects, validAccounts will now contain an array of valid objects
var validAccounts = accountObjects.filter(function (a) {
    return a.valid;
});

// back to the original type of a string array
var validEmailAddresses = validAccounts.map(function (a) {
    return a.email;
});
```

Comment: I tried this and when I checked the output of `validAccounts`, it says that `admin1@google.com` was valid even though `admin` is a blacklisted word

Comment: @SBB swapped out `indexOf` for `search`, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using javascript array native functions:

```
var invalidAccounts = newAccounts.filter(function(account){ // we need to filter accounts
  return blacklist.some(function(word){ // and return those that have any of the words in the text
      return account.indexOf(word) != -1
  })
});
```

More info on: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and 
[Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some of the things...

```
for (var x = 0; x < newAccounts.length; x++) // loop through new accounts
{
    // for every account check if there is any match in blacklist array
    for (var y = 0; y < blacklist.length; y++) 
    {
      // if there is match do something 
      if (newAccounts[x].indexOf(blacklist[y]) > -1)
      {
          alert(newAccounts[x] + " is in the blacklist array");
          break;
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need two loops to achieve this: 
something like below:

```
   // Loop over the blacklist array
  for(var j = 0; x < newAccounts.length; j++){
    for(var x = 0; x < blacklist.length; x++){
    if(newAccounts[j].indexOf(blacklist[x]) > -1){
        alert(blacklist[x] + " is in the blacklist array");
        // Push the newAccounts value into the invalidAccounts array since it contains a blacklist word.
      }else{
        alert('no matches');
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/n1rkfuzh/

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// Create our arrays
var blacklist = ["admin", "webform", "spoof"];
var newAccounts = ["admin1@google.com", "interweb@google.com", "puppy@google.com"];
var invalidAccounts = [];

for(var x = 0; x < newAccounts.length; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < blacklist.length; y++){


          if( newAccounts[x].indexOf(blacklist[y]) > -1){
            alert(blacklist[x] + " is in the blacklist array");
            // Push the newAccounts value into the invalidAccounts array since it contains
            // a blacklist word.
            invalidAccounts.push(newAccounts[x]);
          }else{
            alert('no matches');
          }
    }
}
```